# The terms "calling function" below, do they refer to a function that calls the function, whose parameter is being initialized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[expr.call]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#4) in C++1z (emphasis is mine):

> When a function is called, each parameter ([dcl.fct]) shall be
> initialized ([dcl.init], [class.copy], [class.ctor]) with its
> corresponding argument. If the function is a non-static member
> function, the this parameter of the function ([class.this]) shall be
> initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if
> by an explicit type conversion ([expr.cast]). [ Note: There is no
> access or ambiguity checking on this conversion; the access checking
> and disambiguation are done as part of the (possibly implicit) class
> member access operator. See [class.member.lookup],
> [class.access.base], and [expr.ref].  — end note ] When a function is
> called, the parameters that have object type shall have
> completely-defined object type. [ Note: this still allows a parameter
> to be a pointer or reference to an incomplete class type. However, it
> prevents a passed-by-value parameter to have an incomplete class type.
> — end note ] It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a
> parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at
> the end of the enclosing full-expression. The initialization and
> destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
> **calling function**. [ Example: the access of the constructor, conversion functions or destructor is checked at the point of call in
> the **calling function**. If a constructor or destructor for a
> function parameter throws an exception, the search for a handler
> starts in the scope of the **calling function**; in particular, if the
> function called has a function-try-block (Clause [except]) with a
> handler that could handle the exception, this handler is not
> considered.  — end example ]

My understanding is that the terms **calling function** above refer to a function that calls the function, whose parameter is being initialized. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, you don't need to call a function from inside another function. Think of namespace scope initializers.

Comment: @Columbo I had thought about this. That's was exactly what confused me.

Comment: "Calling function" is not a technical term. It means what it sounds like it means in plain English.

Comment: I recommend making a defect report on std-discussion or sending a mail to richard

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that the terms calling function above refer to a function that calls the function, whose parameter is being initialized. Is that correct?

That is correct, but is a defect and is subject to recently filed [defect report 2715: [expr.call] "Calling function" is not clearly defined, and may not exist](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/287), which sought to clarify this because

> a function call that is a subexpression of an init-declarator for a non-local variable does not have a calling function, and some expressions that are evaluated during translation do not have calling functions

Which means that the current wording leaves out some relevant cases. The [current proposed resolution](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2715.html) seeks to clarify this to say (*emphasis mine*):

> The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs `within the context of the full-expression` (6.9.1 [intro.execution]) where the function call appears.

Comment: Worth noting, I only opened that issue because I saw this question. I try to give credit in such cases, but Jens won't put it on the actual issues page :)